# Is there a way to change the default log level of Hazelcast?

Tags: hazelcast

I am trying to start the hazelcast using the default hazelcast.xml and the start script provide by hazelcast. I am setting the logging type to log4j2 in the hazelcast.xml. I am seeing this message in the logs.

**ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console. Set system property 'log4j2.debug' to show Log4j2 internal initialization logging.**

I couldn't figure out the way to change the default log level. Could anyone help me on how to set the default log level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me,
`export JAVA_OPTS="-Dhazelcast.logging.type=log4j2 -Dlog4j.configurationFile=./log4j2.xml"`

And then have a file named `log4j2.xml` in the current folder containing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">

    <Appenders>
    <Console name="ConsoleRed" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%red{%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n}"/>
    </Console>
    <Console name="ConsoleWhite" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%white{%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n}"/>
    </Console>
    <Console name="ConsoleYellow" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%yellow{%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n}"/>
    </Console>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
    <Logger name="com.hazelcast" level="info" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleYellow"/>
    </Logger>
    <Logger name="com.hazelcast.core" level="info" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleRed"/>
    </Logger>

    <Root level="error">
            <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleWhite"/>
    </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

If you have colours on, you'll see different colours for the different types of messages.